# Package reference not restored

Tags: c#, .net, compiler-errors

I'm encountering an issue with package restoration and referencing in my ASP.NET multiproject solution.  Despite configuring the NuGet package sources correctly, the packages are not being referenced or restored. Here are the steps I've taken to troubleshoot:

- Verified NuGet Package Sources: Confirmed that the package sources are correctly configured in "Tools" -> "Options" -> "NuGet Package Manager" -> "Package Sources."
- Attempted Package Restoration from Command Line: Ran nuget restore solution.sln from the command line to check for any hidden errors or warnings.
- Tried deleting packages folder in the root directory and restored packages. All packages are already installed and there is nothing to restore.this message is returned but still those, references are missing.

this reference issue is not in other branch, It was also not there in current But I had clone the repo again since then this problem is there

[Reference missing](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TAoVB.png)

Despite these efforts, the packages are still not being restored or referenced. Any suggestions or further troubleshooting steps would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have encountered similar scenarios in WPF and here's what I did.

1. Take a fresh pull from the repo.
2. Expand the references in project to see if there are any reference errors (like your attached image)
3. Remove the references with errors
4. Go to properties -> Projects -> Solution -> Select the references from there if available or go to Browse and try to locate the dll's.

If it is in NuGet, what I usually do is that uninstall the references and try to install them again.

Comment: I did fresh pull and missing nuget was in packages folder I add the missing reference.

Comment: I did fresh pull and missing nuget was in packages folder I add the missing reference.